# Placing the copula だ not at the end of a sentence

Tags: copula

In

> お酒は、ほろ酔いのうちが最高**だ**と言われる。
>
> It's said that alcohol is the best while tipsy.

there is a だ placed before the end of a sentence. I was under the impression that だ can *only* be placed at the end of the sentence (excluding sentence ending particles), or else it must take its な form.  Is this not the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotative と uses the 終止形 and not the 連体形. This is one of the few instances where they're different in modern Japanese. Surely you've seen だと思う?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's possible/probable I've seen it, but for some reason have never noticed it in the 終止形 form until now.